# Parsing XML and getiing the root element

Tags: apex, xml

I am trying to parse an xml and get its root element but when I try it Im getting all the elements as a result of getrootelement() method.

```
String xml = '<results>'
+ '<status code="ok"/>'
+ '<principal-list>'
+     '<principal principal-id="1089714827" account-id="1089571079" type="user" has-children="false" is-primary="false" is-hidden="false" training-group-id="">'
+         '<name>Research</name>'
+         '<login>events@Research.com</login>'
+         '<email>events@Research.com</email>'
+         '<display-uid>events@Research.com</display-uid>'
+     '</principal>'
+ '</principal-list>'
+ '</results>';

   Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
   doc.load(xml);

  Dom.XmlNode results = doc.getRootElement();
  system.debug(results);
```

According to the above example the root element must be "**results**" and since im not iterating further my debug log should show only "**results**" but im getting the entire xml as output.Where im going wrong ? or my way of understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the root element, but your debug statement is outputting the whole Dom.XmlNode object, whereas you only want the name of the root element.

Try replacing the system.debug statement with `system.debug(results.getName());`